# In requireJS, requesting global scripts more than one?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm making a requireJS/backbone/jquery app and I'm wondering do I need to require in those global libraries in every script?

```
// App View

define(
[
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
],
function($, _, Backbone) {
    var App = Backbone.View.extend( /* code here */ )
    return App;
});

// and then later in my application:
// Router

define(
[
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
],
function($, _, Backbone) {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend( /* code here */ )
    return Router;
});
```

etc.

Or once they are loaded in my global app view can I forget about them?  Can I just:

```
// App View

define(
[
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
],
function($, _, Backbone) {
    var App = Backbone.View.extend( /* code here */ )
    return App;
});

// and then later in my application:
// Router

define(
[],
function() {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend( /* code here */ )
    return Router;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always declare the dependencies. It's bad practice to rely on global variables, and defeats the point of using RequireJS for module management.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  It just seemed a little long-winded to require the same dependencies over and over again.  I suppose I could get over this by creating a base router/view/model etc and extending those so there's only one place that requires in these libs per module.